# 3D print retouch with soldering iron

Tags: post-processing

Does anyone have any information about using a soldering iron to fix and retouch 3D prints?
On the market, for example, we can find Modifi3D pen. Why has nobody created a simple soldering tip for this use?

I have a TS100 soldering iron which has great temperature control and I think it would be perfect for this use.

Does anyone think it's a bad idea?

Answer (score 2):

I have used a standard soldering iron to modify and fix 3D prints in the past. You have to keep some things in mind when doing so:

- Don't overheat your material. PLA can take a soldering iron of about 230 °C before charring.
- Don't use a tip with solder, or you will get grey deposits in the plastic.
- Round tips or flat tips both work fine, but you want to not dump *too* much heat into the model or you start to deform the print as it needs to cool again.
- Using snippets from the end of the spool for soldering is a good way to recycle the "waste".

Answer (score 1):

Cutting materials with a 'hot knife' isn't anything new.  There should be a fairly established toolset for working foam.  For 3D prints, I prefer to add coatings rather than modify surfaces with a hand held tool after.  I do run a drill bit through printed holes though.